# Turn off display after n seconds in shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts, zenity, syntax

```
#!/bin/sh
(
time=$( zenity --scale --min-value=0 --max-value=20 --text="Pls Select Time in(s)")
)
&& sleep $time && xset dpms force off
```

I wanted to turn off display after n seconds, but this does not quite work...
expert's advise please...

Comment: just realized it was a very minor syntax error...

[code]( time=$(zenity --scale --min-value=0 --max-value=20 --text="Pls Select Time in(s)") && sleep $time && xset dpms force off )

Comment: works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP wrote:

> just realized it was a very minor syntax error:
>
> ```
> ( time=$(zenity --scale --min-value=0 --max-value=20 --text="Pls Select Time in(s)") && sleep $time && xset dpms force off )
> ```

Comment: how did you do that ... the code part @radu ? (i'm new to this forum so i am a dummy)

Comment: @LinuxSudo See http://askubuntu.com/editing-help